# Is there a way to do a fresh install of just Ubuntu and wipe the hard drive completely?

Tags: installation, boot-failure, hp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I have an older HP laptop that came with Vista. Instead of installing Win8, I installed Ubuntu as an application where it prompts for Windows or Ubuntu during the boot process.

Well, Windows has not been booting for a year... I think it was crushed by a virus. I'm happily using Ubuntu but I'm wondering if there's a way to do a fresh install of just Ubuntu and wipe the hard drive completely with this unique setup where Ubuntu is attached to Windows but I can't get into Windows?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, and for that you'll need to make an Ubuntu installation CD/USB (also known as Live CD/USB), and boot from it. When the desktop loads, click the Install button, and follow along, then, at stage 4 (see the guide), select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu".

That should take care of wiping the disk out completely.

[Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-ubuntu)

[Live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

[Installation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Last, but not least, backup whatever files you want to keep before you start, and then restore them after the installation.

Comment: Also copy any files from Vista partition that might be useful, as part of your backup ..

Comment: Eraze and lease :)

Comment: can i use one computer to make the startup disk, and then install it on a different computer?  i guess i just want to make sure that i can follow these instructions to make the bootable USB with a different computer than the one i want to wipe.

Comment: @dbliss Yes, you can. It doesn't matter which computer is used to make the bootable USB.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do a fresh install.

My preferred way to do this is to [**download the Ubuntu Desktop image**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) from Ubuntu website, and while in your "old" Ubuntu environment [**create a bootable USB flash drive**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu). For example, open the "Dash" (hit the "Windows" button if you have it on your keyboard) and type "Startup Disk Creator", and you should see a program icon below for the utility to upload the downloaded image to the flash drive. You may also make a bootable USB [from Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [from MAC OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

This helps with computers that do not have a CD or DVD drive, and also appears to be a faster installation. As a bonus, you will have the USB stick as a live Ubuntu to go and boot any other computer from it.

Answer (score 1):

Please [downlaod](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Ubuntu version you want to install and then burn it into a CD / DVD.

Boot from the DVD and choose

**Install Ubuntu**

[image]

Then move with choices till you reach this window

[image]

Now if you want to remove windows You have to choose the second option **"Replace Windows with ...."**

and that's just move with options and you'll got what you wish...

Good luck